# Sorting a tuple that contains tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have the following tuple, which contains tuples:

```
MY_TUPLE = (
    ('A','Apple'),
    ('C','Carrot'),
    ('B','Banana'),
)
```

I'd like to sort this tuple based upon the **second** value contained in inner-tuples (i.e., sort Apple, Carrot, Banana rather than A, B, C).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

MY_SORTED_TUPLE = tuple(sorted(MY_TUPLE, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

or without `itemgetter`:

```
MY_SORTED_TUPLE = tuple(sorted(MY_TUPLE, key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Comment: Of note: if the value you're sorting by can have duplicates, you can fallback to another value by giving additional arguments to [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), e.g. `itemgetter(1, 0)`.

Comment: Should be "from operator import itemgetter".

Answer (score 7):

From [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#head-d121eed08556ad7cb2a02a886788656dadb709bd)

> Often there's a built-in that will
>   match your needs, such as str.lower().
>   The operator module contains a number
>   of functions useful for this purpose.
>   For example, you can sort tuples based
>   on their second element using
>   operator.itemgetter():

```
>>> import operator 
>>> L = [('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('a', 4), ('b', 3)]
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(0), L)
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(1), L)
[2, 1, 4, 3]
>>> sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[('d', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 4)]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
sorted(my_tuple, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

In other words, when comparing two elements of the tuple you're sorting, sort based on the return value of the function passed as the key parameter.

Answer (score -2):

I achieved the same thing using this code, but your suggestion is great. Thanks!

```
templist = [ (line[1], line) for line in MY_TUPLE ] 
templist.sort()
SORTED_MY_TUPLE = [ line[1] for line in templist ]
```

Comment: Ouch!  Why make three copies of everything?  Seems excessive to me.  For  a large collection of data, this will be pretty slow.