# Sorting a tuple that contains lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222752/sorting-a-tuple-that-contains-tuples) but instead my tuple contains lists, as follows:

```
mytuple = (
 ["tomato", 3],
 ["say", 2],
 ["say", 5],
 ["I", 4],
 ["you", 1],
 ["tomato", 6],
)
```

What's the most efficient way of sorting this?

Comment: which field do you want to sort by?

Comment: You can't sort a tuple.  It's immutable.

Comment: And semantically a tuple does not even make sense in this situation. Sorting a tuple in general does not make any sense since a list should have been used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a sorted tuple easy enough:

```
>>> sorted(mytuple)
[['I', 4], ['say', 2], ['say', 5], ['tomato', 3], ['tomato', 6], ['you', 1]]
```

This will sort based on the items in the list. If the first two match, it compares the second, etc.

If you have a different criteria, you can provide a comparison function.

**Updated:** As a commenter noted, this returns a list.  You can get another tuple like so:

```
>>> tuple(sorted(mytuple))
(['I', 4], ['say', 2], ['say', 5], ['tomato', 3], ['tomato', 6], ['you', 1])
```

Comment: By "get a sorted tuple" do you mean "create a new tuple that's sorted"?

Comment: This is hugely inefficient however - why not just take mluebke's advice and use a list to begin with? S. Lott is right -- you cannot sort a tuple in place.

Comment: I'm trying to process output from psycopg2, which uses Python's DB-API and therefore outputs tuples.

Comment: The DB-API .fetch functions typically return lists (rows) of tuples (records), not tuples of lists. Please provide sample code and data.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot sort a tuple.

What you can do is use [sorted()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) which will not sort the tuple, but will create a sorted list from your tuple. If you really need a sorted tuple, you can then cast the return from sorted as a tuple:

```
mytuple = tuple(sorted(mytuple, key=lambda row: row[1]))
```

This can be a waste of memory since you are creating a list and then discarding it (and also discarding the original tuple).  Chances are you don't need a tuple. Much more efficient would be to start with a list and sort that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to instantiate a new tuple, unfortunately: something like

```
mytuple = sorted(mytuple)
```

should do the trick.  `sorted` won't return a tuple, though.  wrap the call in `tuple()` if you need that.  This could potentially be costly if the data set is long.

If you need to set on the second element in the sublists, you can use the `key` parameter to the `sorted` function.  You'll need a helper function for that:

```
mytuple = sorted(mytuple, key=lambda row: row[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique used in the accepted answer to that question (`sorted(..., key=itemgetter(...))`) should work with any iterable of this kind.  Based on the data you present here, I think the exact solution presented there is what you want.