# sorting list in python accoeding to one dimension

Tags: python, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a tuple that contains tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222752/sorting-a-tuple-that-contains-tuples)

hi
I have a list that goes A=[[a,'3'],[g,'1'],[y,2]]
I am looking for a quick way to arrange it according to the numbers (second dimension), so
NewA=[[g,'1'],[y,'2'],[a,'3']]
thanks
ariel

Comment: The input/output is inconsistant, it is likely supposed to be the string '2' and not the int 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
newA = sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This returns: [['y', 2], ['g', '1'], ['a', '3']]

Comment: @AA: What kind of Python are you using? http://ideone.com/Du1qg

Comment: @a-a, the question's input/output is inconsistent, mixing strings and ints.

Comment: Aah my bad, I see where I was wrong.

Comment: @Kenny, @AA it returns the results, because `2` is an integer, and `1`, `3` are strings. It compares type names `str` and `int`.

Comment: @khachik: Right. It could be taken care by `sorted(a, key=lambda x:str(x[1]))`, but I don't think this is appropriate here.