# how to sort tuple in python?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a tuple that contains tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222752/sorting-a-tuple-that-contains-tuples)

I am having some trouble with sorting a tuple which contain number and string.
in the beginning, I have a tuple like this:

```
a=(("a",2),("b",2),("a",1))
```

then how can I sort it into: (by number first then alphabetical)

```
a=(("a",1),("a",2),("b",2))
```

Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: Yep, I agree, seems to be an exact dupe.

Comment: Definitly a duplicate. And man, that's the first 5 entries in Google for "sort tuple".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a=(("a",2),("b",2),("a",1))
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1, 0))
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: Did you know you can use `itemgetter(1, 0)` to get two items at once? No need to call `sorted` twice.

Comment: Nope, didn't know that one. Thanks for that.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this returns a list while the question specifically wants a tuple as the output. Sometimes this can matter.

Answer (score 3):

Tuples cannot be sorted by definition because they are immutable.  You can convert this to a list, sort the list, and then convert back to tuple.  Something like this,

```
mylist = sorted(a, key = lambda x: str(x[1])+str(x[0]))
a = tuple(mylist)
```

Comment: Sorted converts it to a list automatically. No need to do list(a) first.

Comment: Didn't know that, but will keep in mind from now on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function [sorted](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) will do that for you.