# Sorting a list of tuples according to the first element

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have to sort a list of tuples according to the second element. I am using the function sort() to do so. However, what I did isn't working...

```
   def sort_tuple(to_sort):
        sort_tuple=((3, 'C'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'))
        sort_tuple.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])  
        return sort_tuple
```

And if I had to sort it according to the first element, would the code be what I wrote under?:

```
   def sort_tuple(to_sort):
        sort_tuple=((3, 'C'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'))
        sort_tuple.sort
        return sort_tuple
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are making a fairly basic mistake: you want to sort `to_sort`, but you create a new tuple inside the function and proceed to sort and return that. Also, don't name a temporary return value the same as the function, it's confusing and prevents recursion. A final problem is the premise of your function: you cannot sort a tuple, it's immutable, you could create a new tuple that is a sorted version of the original though.

Comment: You need to edit the question itself; comments aren't formatted with newlines.

Comment: Why are you making a new `tuple` inside the function and ignoring the argument? Seems like you really just want `to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` and `return to_sort`, or to avoid mutating the caller's argument (a good idea since you're returning the sorted value anyway, and both mutating and returning the mutated value is confusing and frowned upon in Python, and to allow non-`list` inputs), the even simpler `return sorted(to_sort, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: so instead of sort_tuple, I should write to_sort? But when I do that, I also get nothing in return...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a tuple that contains tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222752/sorting-a-tuple-that-contains-tuples)

Comment: @Anthony: You need to provide a true [MCVE]; as written, if you actually called this, you'd get a guaranteed `AttributeError` (`tuple`s don't have a `sort` method). Provide enough code to actually reproduce your entire error, as well as an example input, expected output, and observed output (including full traceback, if you get an exception).

Comment: `xxx.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])` says to sort according to the second element.  `xxx.sort(),` when the values are tuples says to sort using lexicographic sort:  compare the first element of the tuple, and if they are the same, then use the second element, and so on. (Lexicographic sort is the way you naturally sort words.). If you want to sort by the first element and completely ignore everything else. `xxx.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])`.   Alternatively `xxx.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))` is a shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

```
def sort_tuple(to_sort):
   return tuple(sorted(to_sort, key = lambda x:x[1]))
```

`sorted()` returns the object sorted, rather than sorting (mutating) it, so here it will transform to_sort into a list and sort it

then as you wanted a tuple, we retransform the list `sorted(to_sort, key = lambda x:x[1])` into a tuple with `tuple()`

Comment: works now, but it seems counterintuitive to have a tuple as the outer object, it should be a list as it is mutable

Comment: the initial question was 2nd element so it is lambda x:x[1] but then 1st element would be lambda x:x[0]

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation for your code

Comment: done, thanks; it's my first time answering something on stack overflow